# Notification of colour changed on CMFCColorButton?

Tags: c++, colors, mfc

I have an MFC Color Button on my dialog. I'd like to detect when a user selects a different colour but can't seem to pick up any notifications.

From reading the documentation I thought this would work;

```
// Within the CPP
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CSampleCode, CDialogEx)
  ON_NOTIFY(BN_CLICKED, IDC_MFCCOLOR_BUTTON, OnColorSelectionChanged)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()



void CSampleCode::OnColorSelectionChanged(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult) 
{
  // Do Something
}
```

I have other controls in the dialog whose notifications I am picking up without problems. Can't seem to get the MFC Color Button to trigger anything though.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Also in the control properties I have set "Notify" to True, still no luck.

Answer (score 3):

From the BCG help files...

> The CBCGColorButton object notifies its parent about color changing by
>   WM_COMMAND | BN_CLICKED  notification. The parent may retrieve the
>   current color by calling GetColor method.

Looks like you're looking for a notify message when you should be trapping WM_COMMAND.